# How to filter characters if lines are aligned to right side using awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed, pattern-matching

I have output of a command which is as given here.

```
                        ID   SPEED    NCPU    PMEM    VMEM      EP   NPROC      IO    IOPS
                        p1     100       1   1024M   1024M      20     100    1024    1024
                        a2     100       1   1024M   1024M      20     100    1024    1024
                     b2 b3     100       1   1024M   1024M      20     100    1024    1024
                  c3 c4 c5     100       1   1024M   1024M      20     100       0    1024
```

I need to filter out the values which come under the column 'ID'

The command `awk '{print $1}` prints only:

```
p1
a2
b2
c3
```

which is not desired output.

The output I'm looking for is.

```
p1
a2
b2 b3
c3 c4 c5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to look at it is 'remove the last eight columns from the data':

```
awk '{ $(NF-8+1) = ""; NF -= 8; print }'
```

Output:

```
ID
p1
a2
b2 b3
c3 c4 c5
```

If you don't assign to `$(NF-8+1)`, `awk` doesn't think `$0` might have changed so it prints the line unchanged.  And the use of `$(NF-8+1)` would allow you to use a variable to specify how many trailing columns to omit:

```
awk -v omit="${howmany:-8}" '{ $(NF-omit+1) = ""; NF -= omit; print }'
```

If you set the shell variable `howmany=6`, you will see the 'SPEED' and 'NCPU' columns too:

```
ID SPEED NCPU
p1 100 1
a2 100 1
b2 b3 100 1
c3 c4 c5 100 1
```

Tested with both BSD and GNU variants of `awk`.

Comment: That's relying on undefined behavior so YMMV. POSIX defines what happens if you increase `NF` (you get a bunch of extra null fields) but not what happens when you decrease it, that's left up to the implementation. You could get a POSIX approach with `sub(/( +[^ ]+){8}$/,"")` though.

Comment: That seems to be a fair comment — at least per the POSIX [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)
 specification.  You can increase `NF` by assigning to a field beyond the current value: `$(NF+1) = 6; $(NF+1) = 7;` actually assigns to two different fields, which isn't immediately obvious.  It's not clear that `NF += 2` is defined, or that `NF -= 7` is defined.  It happens to work; it is not clear that it must work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR>1{$0=substr($0,1,26); $1=$1; print}' file
p1
a2
b2 b3
c3 c4 c5
```

Note, however that the general solution to dealing with fixed width fields as you have is to use GNU awk's FIELDWIDTHS variable instead of FS:

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="26 8 8 8" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "<%s>%s", gensub(/^ +/,"",1,$i), (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}' file
<ID> <SPEED> <NCPU> <PMEM>
<p1> <100> <1> <1024M>
<a2> <100> <1> <1024M>
<b2 b3> <100> <1> <1024M>
<c3 c4 c5> <100> <1> <1024M>
```

I added the gensub() to remove leading spaces. See:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size
- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions

Answer (score 0):

I would also add **sed** option:

```
$ sed -ne '2,$s/^[ ]\+//g; s/\(.*[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]\).*/\1/p' file
p1
a2
b2 b3
c3 c4 c5
```

Where:

```
2,$ - start with 2nd line
s/^[ ]\+//g - remove leading spaces
s/\(.*[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]\).*/\1/p - match until last [alpha][digit] and print only that part
```

NOTE: I assumed that IDs are always like `a1` or `b2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If number of characters for the field is fixed

```
grep -oE '^.{26}' file
```

Pipe the output to `tail -n +2` if first line is not required.. or use `sed`

```
sed -nE '2,$ s/^(.{26}).*/\1/p' file
```

If number of fields are fixed:

```
$ sed -nE '2,$ s/(\s+\S+){8}$//p' file
                        p1
                        a2
                     b2 b3
                  c3 c4 c5
```